# Derivative of two arrays

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to calculated `dy/dx` using two values from two arrays, the code I have so far is:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim x = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0}
        Dim y = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 7.0, 15.0, 23.0, 31.0, 39.0, 47.0, 55.0, 61.0, 64.0}
        Dim m() As Double

        For i = 0 To x.Length - 2
            m = (y(i + 1) - y(i)) / (x(i + 1) - (x(i)))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(m)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I was hoping that this code would store all values of dy/dx into the array m, however when I run my code all I get is: 3 (the final value of dy/dx)

Comment: Does that even compile? `m` is an array but you treat it like a single `Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, your declaration is not clear, like @Visual Vincent stated in a comment. I think it should be:

```
Dim m() As Double = New Double(16) {}
```

Then in the loop, you're always assigning the new value to the `Double` value. Here's what that line should look like:

```
m(i) = (y(i + 1) - y(i)) / (x(i + 1) - (x(i)))
```

*Edit:*

To write all values to the console, use following code:

```
For Each d As Double In m
    Console.WriteLine(d)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Abbas's answer will fix the issue you asked about, but also keep in mind what the desired end-result is. m isn't quite dy/dx because if x is of length 16, m will be of length 15. m(0) doesn't correspond to the approximate slope of x(0), but rather to the approximate slope of x(0.5).